# Spring JPA Delete Query with RowCount

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-mvc, jpa

I have a Spring Boot application with a JPARepository to manage my data in a MySQL Database. At the moment I have this Query Annotation:

```
@Query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Tweetpost t")
int findRowCount();
```

With int `findRowCount();` I can see how much Rows are filled in the DB, now I want to delete all Rows, that are over 100. So the database should never have more than 100 rows, otherwise it should delete everything above 100. I only have this yet:

```
@Modifying
@Transactional
@Query(DELETE)
int removeOldRows();
```

Comment: So what is the question here?

Comment: And how you will define, which rows have be deleted? Should it be oldest rows, or should it be rows with minimal value of particular field?

Comment: Just the oldestRows. So if I have 105 records in the db, it should delete the oldest 5..

Comment: There is no row limiting in JQL, you can use spring JPA and create a method named simpler to findTop100OrderById, this will return a list, you will then have to iterate over the list and delete each entity.

Comment: But I can count the rows, so I should be able to limit them I think..

Comment: Id just write a custom query

Comment: @EssexBoy generally, you right, except one thing. It would be better to delete all rows by on query. Too much separate queries may cause of performance issue.

Comment: BTW, a little bit off topic, but your `int findRowCount();` method could be substituted with `count()` [method](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html?is-external=true#count--)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately JPQL can not use `limit` key word. But you can do it in two steps. First - get limited list of latest id. Second - delete all tweets, which ids are not in this list. I suppose, since you want to delete oldest records, you have something like `date` column.

Declare in repository two methods:

```
@Repository
public TweetpostRepository extends CrudRepository<Tweetpost , Integer>{

    @Query("select t.id from TweetPost t order by t.date desc")
    public Page<Integer> findLatestId(Pageable pageable);

    @Modifying
    @Transactional
    @Query("delete from TweetPost t where t.id not in (:idList)")
    public void deleteByExcludedId(@Param("idList") List<Integer> idList);

    ...
}
```

Note, that we use `desc` sorting, because we need ids of the *latest* records. Now you can use it in Controller next way:

```
@Service
public class MyService {

    @Autowired
    private TweetpostRepository repository;

    public void trunkateTweetposts(){
        Page<Integer> page = repository.findLatestId(new PageRequest(0, 10));
        repository.deleteByExcludedId(page.getContent());
        ...
    }

}
```

In this example `10` is the count of records you wish to keep.

Comment: There are some mistakes in your code. In the Repo your wrote "Latest" with two T's and in the Controller you meant public void I think.

Comment: @julien thanx, I corrected typo. I thought method in contoller will return redirect string. For example redirect back to list view. But, of couse, if you don't need it, you can use `public void`. In case if you will do this scenario with ajax.

Comment: no it should only belonge to the backend, where I have a Housekeeping Service, which "observes" the DB.

Comment: @julien, oh i see. Then it should be the method of sevice, and `pubilc void`, indeed.